# Black Box appearing behind drop down menu only in chrome on windows machines for mobile screen only?

Tags: google-chrome, menu, background

Has anyone come across the following problem? Please view image [attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9DM9.jpg). 
This problem only exist in chrome on windows machine and on mobile devices. 
A strange black box appears behind the drop down menu

Comment: It might not be the right forum here, but I have the same problem right now.

Answer (score 3):

Try disabling hardware acceleration in Google Chrome.  Go to Chrome Settings, search for hardware acceleration, and uncheck the box if it is checked.  Chrome should prompt you to restart the application.

We were seeing this problem on Chrome version 50.0.2661.87 m.

Comment: I noticed this issue on 53.0.2785.116 m (the black box shows up randomly in the blank/white area when on mobile testing ion Dev Tools unsually). Ill try the hardware accel fix

Comment: Didn't help. Issue persists. Version 53.0.2785.143 m - black box replaces option drop-down list, typically significantly offset from the actual select.